# Magento 2 cache solution needed

Tags: magento, caching

Hi I'm looking for a cache solution that will allow us to see changes we make across our site much quicker. At the moment we have a cache that runs routinely every day at 1am. The issue I have is that if I want to make changes on the site such as catalog price rules, block changes and category updates, I don't see this until the following day.

Ideally I'd see these changes instantly. Thanks in advance for any tips.
Ronnie

Comment: you can manually refresh the cache after any change from admin panel

Comment: Hi, yes I see this but this just slows the site to a standstill.

Comment: When you clear/refresh cache then Magento create this cache again as you load/visit the site and due to this site takes more time to load. And this is the Major reason that cache has set routine at 1 am So the site won't suffer at day time.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to programatically clean it and flush the cache

You can do this in magento 2, but you have to do it manually in your code

The way to do this is:

**1. Inject these classed into you constructor dependency**

```
private $_cacheTypeList;
private $_cacheFrontendPool;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
) {
    ...
    $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
    $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
}
```

**2. Write this code inside of your class**

```
$types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
}
foreach ($this->_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
    $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
}
```

Inside of the `$types` array you have all the type of cache you want to clean

Also magento 2 has areas so, you have cache tyes and frontend pool cache types as well.

This will refresh all the types you've entered inside you `$types` array.

Check magento documentation for all cache types that are available in [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html)

to clean only the ones you need, instead of every single one of them